# c# point class assignment, homework (NOT cheating)

Tags: c#, class, point

I have a little problem. In my homework assignment, I must create and implement a `Point` `class` which represents a `point` on the `console` screen. It should mark out the character " * " in a specific place on the `console` window. The `console` page should, for example, be 80 pixels wide and it should have a maximum height of 49 pixels. There is also a hint on the assignent, which says that I should look for the `Console.SetCursorPosition()` method in `MSDN`.

So, how far have I come? Well, I have created a `class` called "point", declared 2 `int` variables x and y for the coordinator and created a constructor. But I'm not sure if the constructor should take in those 2 variables as arguments, and what it should do with them.

NOTE: I DON'T want people to write me the whole code for this; that's not the way I learn. I'm writing here so people with more experience in `C#` than me can help me direct me to the right way.

Comment: You'll stay open longer and get fewer negative votes if you'd post the alleged code that you've created.  It will demonstrate some good will and let people see that you've actually done something.

Comment: so did you look for the `Console.SetCursorPosition()` method in MSDN ?

Comment: @AbZy why should he look at the `Console.SetCursorPosition()` method if it does not concern his question? The question was in regards to architecture and initialization of an objects members, not about the background story?

Comment: @AndreasWallner The OP Says : `There is also a hint on the assignent, wich says that I should look for the Console.SetCursorPosition() method in MSDN.`

Comment: @AbZy I still don't see how the page helps to answer the question.

Comment: @AndreasWallner have a look at the [Console.SetCursorPosition()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx) method in MSDN, you will find a complete example and this at least gives him/her a head start.

Comment: @AbZy I did. If I read the question correctly, the OP wants to know what/how a constructor should work (see also my answer). If I'm right, the example provides no information. (Yes it will provide information later on when using the object, but not on "how to write a constructor")

Answer (score 1):

IMO a class representing a position should be an immutable value object, so it should get value semantics.

What I'd do:

- create a class `ConsolePoint`
- have to `private readonly int` fields to store the value of the coordinates
- have two public properties whose getters return the value of the fields, no setters
- have a constructor that takes the two coordinates, throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if they're invalid, and then assigns to the fields.

Then to implement value equality:

- Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`
- Overload `==` and `!=`.

All four of those should be consistent.

---

But if you prefer a mutable class, I'd create two mutable fields, and two properties whose setters validate the coordinates. This works well since the validation of the two coordinates is independent. In that case I'd just use the default constructor.

Comment: If the object is immutable, I would also add a method that returns a new `ConsolePoint` but with changed coordinates, like `move( int dx, int dy)`

Answer (score 0):

You said that you were directed to the [`Console.SetCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx) method - that page, specifically the examples section, should be extremely useful for you.

As far as your class, it would be easier to give advice if you'd posted some code. There are several common ways to set variables on an instance of a class in C#: if they are [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), you could pass values in on the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) and have the constructor do the assignment, or if they are [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) you could just set them directly.

Comment: I don't see how the `Console.SetCursorPosition` documentation answers the question posed in any regard. You are right though that the OP should have posted some code, at least to demonstrate good will.

Comment: @AndreasWallner It's a little hard to tell if OP is *only* asking about constructor semantics, or about the actual method to write something to a specific place on the console. I interpreted the phrase `But im not sure if the constructor should take in those 2 variables as arguments, **and what it should do with them**` as asking two things; 1) how to get variables set in a class and 2) how to use those values to accomplish the goal of writing to a place on the console. Without further clarity from OP I think it's ambiguous.

Comment: I see your point, I would have read it as 'what the constructor should to with the parameters', but you can easily read it in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

In general you are stumbling into territory that is sometimes discussed with religious fervor. Some people advocate a one-phase initialization process, where the constructor always yields a valid and usable object or throws an exception. The second idea is that the constructor gives you a 'blank' object, that you call e.g. an `init()` method later on. The object would not be usable as given by the constructor. This would be called two-phase initialization.

I happen to be somewhere in the middle ground, but leaning to the one-phase init. Sometimes two-phase initialization has its applications, IMO in most cases it does not. Other answer have suggested to make `Point` an immutable object, in this case you have to initialize it with your constructor.

Apart from making your object immutable: If there is no good reason *not* to initialize it in your constructor, don't do it. If you do not initialize values on construction you would have to detect usage of the class before it is initialized (at least I would, to prevent errors down the road), without having an advantage from it.

For what the constructor should do: check the values against max/min values and initialize the fields. If out of bounds, throw an exception.
If your object is mutable, don't forget to do the same thing in your set methods.

In this case you might consider using properties and making the class immutable like CodesInChaos describes in his answer.

Comment: In C#, your members are guaranteed to be initialized to 0.. so a Point would be valid without constructor arguments (unless for some reason 0,0 is invalid). Also, as CodesInChaos mentioned, such a structure really should be immutable (no setter methods as you have suggested).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Thanks for the hint... Didn't know that members are guaranteed to be initialized to 0 in C#, I'll change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities. One way to do it is to write a constructor that takes in two parameters that correspond to the two fields `x` and `y` that you have in your class. The constructor "body" should then assign the first parameter to `x`, and the second to `y`.

Note that if you choose to name your constructor parameters exactly the same as the fields, then the identifier `x` refers to the parameter, not to the field. In that case you will need to write `this.x` to refer to the field.